# Identify column names in R that contain white spaces

Tags: r, vector, dplyr, whitespace

I have a dataframe

```
df
```

Some columns in the dataframe

```
column1|column2|column3|`column 4`|column5|`column 6`
```

How could I identify column names containing spaces (`column 4` and `column 6`) and export them as vectors?

```
c(`column 4`,`column 6`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to use `select` from `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
    select(contains("X"))

vec4 <- df$X.column.4.
vec6 <- df$X.column.6.
vec46 <- c(vec4, vec6)
```

Comment: it pulled zero.

Comment: Does you column header actually contain the backslashes  or is it converted by R into `X.column.4.`

Comment: it should have worked when it had the tilda, but nonetheless I put " " and that gave me the result i wanted.

Comment: *meant tilda instead of backslashes. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
  df %>% 
      dplyr::select(contains(' ')) %>%
      names()
```

Comment: Looks simple enough but i'm getting this weird error message Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x `contains()` must be used within a *selecting* function.
i See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-selection-context.html>.
i Input `..1` is `contains(" ")`.

Comment: @user35131 Oups should have been select not filter. Should work now.